# Array splice function weirdness within 2 different arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have `allProducts` prop is passed by Laravel. And it contains 15 elements.

```
<product-list :all-products='@json($products)'></product-list>
```

And in `ProductList` component, I try to keep data of `allProducts` prop by assigning it to another variable, called `result`, then I can use later.

Next, I use splice function to get a portion data from `result`, and assign to `products`. So the `products` and `result` should have the same 9 elements (15 - 6 = 9). However, I don't know why my `allProducts` also has 9 elements (it should be 15 because I didn't splice `allProduct`).

I tried to print out `allProduct` before using splice and it contains 15 elements as I expected but the console.log statement after using splice function only return 9 elements.

```
    export default {
        name: "ProductPage",
        data() {
            return {
                products: [],
                result: []
            }
        },
        props: ['allProducts'],
        created() {
            this.result = this.allProducts;

            // Print 15 products
            console.log(this.allProducts.length);

            this.products = this.result.splice(0, 6);

            // Only print 9 products, even I didn't use splice on allProducts array.
            console.log(this.allProducts.length);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Splice***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates original array,

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or
>   replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

You can use [**slice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead